# Different ways to install numpy, scipy, and matplotlib on macOS via homebrew

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, homebrew

Today I decided to install python and the scipy stack manually, instead of using Anaconda (or Canopy) as I had previously done. I use homebrew on my mac and have python2 and python3 (2.7 and 3.6) installed via homebrew. But reading through the documentation, there are multiple ways to install the scipy stack and I want to know what the differences are. I have tested they independently and they all work.

From the [Homebrew documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html):
`python2 -m pip install numpy scipy matplotlib`
`python3 -m pip install numpy scipy matplotlib`
These are the same two commands that the [Matplotlib installation docuentation](https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#which-python-for-osx) lists for how to install matplotlib through homebrew. Why does this use pip (the system Python 2.7.x's pip) instead of pip2 and pip3 respectively? Is it because you call python2/python3 first?

However, the [SciPy documentation](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) for installing these modules when using homebrew is different:
`brew tap homebrew/science && brew install numpy scipy matplotlib`
(**NOTE:** the matplotlib formula is located in the homebrew/science repository, which is why you need to use `brew tap`.)

Finally, from the command line readout when installing python2 and python3 via homebrew:
`pip2 install numpy scipy matplotlib`
`pip3 install numpy scipy matplotlib`
which are based on the following readouts:

```
Pip and setuptools have been installed. To update them
  pip2 install --upgrade pip setuptools

You can install Python packages with
  pip2 install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html

...

Pip, setuptools, and wheel have been installed. To update them
  pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html
```

So between four sources of documentation, there are three different ways to install scipy when using homebrew and they all work; but how is each different and should one be preferred?

From what I can tell, the first and third methods, which both invoke pip (pip2/pip3), are functionally equivalent - both invoke Homebrew's Python X.X.X's pip - but one implicitly, the other explicitly. I assume this means both methods install the pre-built binary packages from pip in the form of wheels. For the second method, I think it installs homebrew's own formulae for these packages (i.e. maintained separately by homebrew in it's repository).

If this is true, then I assume one should use the second method if you are using a version of python which is maintained by homebrew (i.e. installed via `brew install python` or `python3`). My reasoning is that if you later decide to install another formula via homebrew that has any of the scipy stack as a dependency, it will install those modules again from homebrew's repository if you installed them using pip previously.

As mentioned, I am not sure if my understanding is correct and I have not been able to find any answers, so any insights or confirmations would be appreciated.

Comment: If you plan to use numerical operations with python, install those modules inside a [conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/download.html) environment. It performances better for math. (*so, do not use brew*)

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis seems correct: variants 1 and 3 will install numpy/scipy from the python package index (PyPI) and will use pre-built wheels (if available for your platform, which they most likely are).
Variant 2 installs the brew formula.

As mentioned by @Evhz, the conda packages for numpy and scipy use the Intel Math Kernel library, which can provide significant speedups (not just on Intel processors) versus the packages installed from PyPI or brew, [both](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#numpy-1-16-1-release-notes) of [which](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/numpy) are linked against [OpenBLAS](https://www.openblas.net/).

Concerning which method to prefer: it's not entirely straightforward.

- Yes, on the surface, using `brew` to manage both the python interpreter and the python packages would seem consistent.
- However, homebrew only provides formulae for a handful of python packages, so you'll end up needing to mix with `pip` in any case.
- If you want performance, you go with `conda`, which will be managing both the interpreter and python packages.
- However, also [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo) / [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/repo) still have some catching up to do with PyPI, so you'll likely need to mix with `pip` again.

In the end, there is no perfect solution but as long as you knowingly decide for one, you're unlikely to run into issues.